# Form Input field with name="url" is not working

Tags: forms, jsp

I am using a form in jsp. One of the input fields is a text field with name set to 'url'

```
  URL:<input id="url" name="url" type="text" />
```

When i submit this form, it throws a blank page and the console doesnt tell me anything. When I change the name to name="VenURL", then the form returns an appropriate response.

Is there a restriction on naming an input form field ?

Comment: And your backend code (the servlet/jsp processing the form submission)?

Comment: What do your getter / setter look like?